# CSV Import: editing configurable childs not working

Tags: magento-1.8, csv, importexport

I want to change the price of associated simple product for a configurable product. I want to do it by CSV import. this is my csv file.

```
sku,price,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
L_TABLET_ASUS_TRANSFORMERPAD_TF103CG,300006,,,,
,555555,L_TABLET_ASUS_TRANSFORMERPAD_TF103CG-white,atrb_color,white,2222
```

I put the behavior to "replace existing complex data" and all the values are valid.

The price change in the configurable product works, but for the simple product is not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to set the simple products price separately on a new line in your file and specify the type.

```
sku,type,price,_super_products_sku,_super_attribute_code,_super_attribute_option,_super_attribute_price_corr
L_TABLET_ASUS_TRANSFORMERPAD_TF103CG,configurable,300006,,,,,555555,L_TABLET_ASUS_TRANSFORMERPAD_TF103CG-white,atrb_color,white,2222
L_TABLET_ASUS_TRANSFORMERPAD_TF103CG,simple,300006,,,,,555555,L_TABLET_ASUS_TRANSFORMERPAD_TF103CG-white,atrb_color,white,2222
```

You might also want to take a look at [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) or [UnderstandingE Magmi](https://understandinge.com/product/magmi-installation-wizard/) for an easier to use solution for product imports.

Comment: thanks, you are right. In addition to those 2 lines I wrote, I should add one more line for the simple one. of course the simple one should be defined first.  btw thank you also for the links.